# how to write migration for newly added table in room database android

Tags: android, android-room

Can someone help me here, As i wanted to alter existing room table(User) by adding new column which is object(address).
`

```
 data class UserDetailsEntity (
  @PrimaryKey
  var id: Int = 0,

  @ColumnInfo(name ="name")
    val name:String? = null,

  @ColumnInfo(name = "lastName")
  val lastName: String ?= null,  
 
  @Embedded
  val address:Address ?= null, 

)
 
data class Address (

@ColumnInfo(name ="lat")
 val lat : String? = null,

@ColumnInfo(name = "long")
 val long: String ?= null,  

)
```

`
How to write migration for above scenario? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? What issues have you been having with migration?

Comment: If  i add new object (Address) to existing room table UserDetailsEntity by using @Embedded annotation. Do i need to write migration for this . if yes , can you give small example ?

Comment: Yes you would need to add migration logic, there's not much point me giving an example when there's already documentation for it, are you having any specific issues with it?

Comment: I know how to write migration if existing table is alter by  adding a column with primitive data type. But i did not find any example when table is altered with new object by using @Embedded annotation.

Comment: Embedding an object within a table just embeds the individual fields. So you only have a single table `UserDetailsEntity(name, lastName, lat, long)`. Does that help?

Comment: yes, its helpful . Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to write migration for this? (from comment)

Yes as the table is being altered.

By Embedding the Address then room will consider that a UserDetailsEntity object will have an Address object within it. Room will therefore build the code to set the objects values.

Additionally room will expect the table UserDetailsEntity (or whatever value is associated with the table) to have two extra columns lat and long. Therefore the migration needs to add the 2 columns. You would use 2 `ALTER TABLE <tablename> ADD COLUMN <column_definition>;` in the migration.

- Note if you compile (Ctrl + F9) with the changes made then look in the **Java(generated)** subfolders, whilst in **Android** view of the **Project** window, and then look at the class, followed by **_impl** where you have the **@Database** in the `createAllTables` method. The SQL for the creation of the table will exist. You can then copy and paste the column definitions.

- Example screen shot where the class **Database** is where the `@Database` is coded and thus **Database_impl** is the generated java to look at that has the create table SQL for the tables :-

[image]